# Trying to understand how ActivityProcessed flag works with "Begin a new Dialog" Action in Bot Framework Composer

Tags: botframework, bots, bot-framework-composer

So in Bot framework Composer when you utilize the action "Begin a new Dialog" there is a parameter called "activity processed" that reads "When set to false the dialog that is called can process the current activity".  I can't find any other documentation, information or examples around this flag.  What I'm looking for is a simple example of its usage.  Can someone point me in a direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activity Processed option it set to false , The entire activity object should be forward (skill)
[here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/3205) you can find some information about this